# Powershell command - from the command prompt

Tags: powershell, command, prompt

I am trying to use the "powershell"  command from the command line, but not is happening, it tells me "Powershell"  is not recognized as an Internal or external command or operabble program or batchfile....

Thnx, APS

Comment: Please show us what exactly you're doing. How do you run the PowerShell command? And what exactly is the result?

Answer (score 0):

PS executables are in folders that are not included the %Path% environment variable. So you need to use full path:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Or if for some reason you need 32-bit PS on 64-bit Windows:

```
%SystemRoot%\Syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

It's a lot of typing so there are easier ways if you just need an interactive PS shell. But it's still useful for calling unsigned scripts from shared folders or network drives with `-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` option.

Comment: yeah, I am there... but when I enter the command, nothing happen.

Comment: @user3754172, What do you expect to happen? The result will usually just be that the command prompt turns into an interpreter for powershell.

Comment: You can basically use powershell in 3 ways:

1 - Launch a script (powershell.exe -File myScript.ps1)
2 - Launch a command (powershell.exe -Command "Get-Command help")
3 - Launch the command interpreter